# How can I reverse a section of a list using a loop in Python?

Tags: python, list, function, loops, reverse

I'm in need of a little help reversing a section of a list in Python **using a loop.**

I have a list: `mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`

Also have an index number, this number will tell where to start the reversing. For example, if the reverse-index number is 3, it needs to be something like this: `['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'e', 'f']`

What I currently have:

```
def list_section_reverse(list1, reverse_index):
    print("In function reverse()")

    n_list = []

    for item in range( len(list1) ):
        n_list.append( (list1[(reverse_index - 1) - item]) )
        item += 1
    return n_list

mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
print( list_section_reverse(mylist, 3) )
```

Which returns `['c', 'b', 'a', 'f', 'e', 'd']`

How can I alter my code, so that it prints out `['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'e', 'f']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it allowed to make a copy of the list?

```
def list_section_reverse(list1, reverse_index):
    print("In function reverse()")

    n_list = [ element for element in list1 ]

    for item in range( reverse_index + 1 ):
        n_list[ item ] = list1[ reverse_index - item ]
        item += 1

    return n_list

mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
print(list_section_reverse(mylist, 3))
```

Outs:

```
In function reverse()
['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: This works, and works with all sizes of Lists. Appreciate it mate, thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped! ^_^

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```
def list_section_reverse(list1, reverse_index):
    return list(reversed(list1[:reverse_index+1])) + list1[reverse_index+1:]
```

**Edit:** The problem with your existing solution is that you keep reversing after `reverse_index`. If you *have to* use a loop, try this:

```
def list_section_reverse(list1, reverse_index):
    print("In function reverse()")

    n_list = list1[:]

    for i in range(reverse_index + 1):
        n_list[i] = list1[-i-reverse_index]
    return n_list

mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
print(list_section_reverse(mylist, 3))
```

Comment: I want to achieve this using a loop, not with built-in functions.

Comment: @Selcuk Sorry, I thought mentioning that I only have to use loops in my title would have been enough. Turns out not.

Comment: @Selcuk Now, I get an error stating `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Comment: @user2572329 It works fine for me, are you sure you are running the same code? Note that initialization of `n_list` has also changed.

Comment: @Selcuk Yep, same code, but different list (same size list). I can't see anything different...

Comment: @Selcuk ah, what would happen if my list size is 4 instead of 6? Should it still reverse without issues? Try and make a list with size 4, and run your code.

Answer (score 2):

The pythonic solution:

```
list1[reverse_index::-1] + list1[reverse_index+1:]
```

Now, that's not using loops like you asked. Well, not explicitly... Instead we can break down the above into its constituent for loops.

```
def list_section_reverse(list1, reverse_index):
    if reverse_index < 0 or reversed_index >= len(list1):
        raise ValueError("reverse index out of range")
    reversed_part = []
    for i in range(reverse_index, -1, -1): # like for i in [n, n-1, ..., 1, 0]
        reversed_part.append(list1[i]

    normal_part = []
    for i in range(reverse_index + 1, len(list1)):
        normal_part.append(list1[i])

    return reversed_part + normal_part
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This makes use of no slicing, and can use either a while loop or for loop.

```
    def reversed_list(my_list, index):
        result = []
        list_copy = my_list.copy()

        i = 0
        while i < index+1:
            result.append(my_list[i])
            list_copy.remove(my_list[i])
            i+=1

        result.reverse()

        return result + list_copy
```

Or with a for loop

```
    def reversed_list(my_list, index):
        result = []
        list_copy = my_list.copy()

        for i in range(len(my_list)):
            if i < index + 1:
                result.append(my_list[i])
                list_copy.remove(my_list[i])

        result.reverse()

        return result + list_copy
```

Comment: oops sorry, I didnt see the loop part in the description. I will add that

Comment: Cheers. Also, if possible, can I accomplish this without slice expressions?

Comment: I updated the answer. Do you still want to remove all sorts of slicing?

Comment: @user2572329, this solution has no slicing, and uses only one loop each.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the list inplace using a slice.

```
mylist[:4] = mylist[:4][::-1]
```